# How can a server get symmetric key from android application?

Tags: android, encryption, aes, aes-gcm

I'm working on an Android application about encryption. And the following codes are used to generate a GCM key:

```
KeyGenerator generator=KeyGenerator.getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES, "AndroidKeyStore");
generator.init(
        new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder("myfirstkey!",
                KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT | KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT)
                .setBlockModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_GCM)
                .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_NONE)
                .setRandomizedEncryptionRequired(false)//use my own iv. I'll change it.
                .setKeySize(128)
                .build());
generator.generateKey();
```

And I plan to send this key to my server first so that I can test whether GCM works or not. So, I use this code to get the key:

```
byte[] bkey=sKey.getEncoded();
```

Of course I failed and I get an error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from null array.
```

According to this question: [Calling .getEncoded() on SecretKey returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42348944/calling-getencoded-on-secretkey-returns-null) 
That's because the KeyStore should be the only one knowing that key. But I am really confused by this: My server needs that key to decrypt the files from the Android application. But I am unable to get the key out of the KeyStore! Are there any way to send the key to the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about GCM, but if you need a secret key which you can move around, you should look into the `javax.crypto` package, which has a very similar API.