# Android convert AES key generated to string (base 64 / hex ...)

Tags: java, android, encryption

Problem Description:

I am working on an android app that will generate an AES key and store it in keystore.

Whenever I need to send data to a server, I use the AES key to encrypt data, use server public key to encrypt the AES key and send encrypted data + encrypted key to the server to decrypt the full load.

the code to generate the Key in android is below:

```
public void generateKey()
{
    try {
        if (!keyStore.containsAlias(KEY_ALIAS)) {
            KeyGenerator keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES, AndroidKeyStore);
            keyGenerator.init(
                    new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(KEY_ALIAS,
                            KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT | KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT)
                            .setBlockModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_GCM).setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_NONE)
                            .setRandomizedEncryptionRequired(false)
                            .build());
            keyGenerator.generateKey();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

When I need to encrypt data i fetch the key using this function

```
private java.security.Key getSecretKey(Context context) throws Exception {
    return keyStore.getKey(KEY_ALIAS, null);
}
```

Using this key I was able to encrypt the data. but the issue is trying to encrypt the key to send it to the server.

I tried to get the key as byte [] to encrypt it but using the function

```
key.getEncoded();
```

the resulting byte array is always null.

What is wrong here and how to solve it?

App is for Android 23+

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure, but you didn't save the key before you do the encryption, make sure you have it on android keystore before.

This kotlin example would help:

```kotlin
@Throws(IOException::class, KeyStoreException::class, CertificateException::class, NoSuchAlgorithmException::class)
    fun saveKeyPair(pair: KeyPair, storeAlias: String) {
        val certificate = generateCertificate(pair)
        val keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore")
        keyStore!!.load(null, null)
        val x509CertificateObject = X509CertificateObject(certificate)
        keyStore.setKeyEntry(storeAlias, pair!!.private, null, arrayOf<java.security.cert.Certificate?>(x509CertificateObject))
    }
```

Hope that could help.

Comment: the generate key function saves the key in the keystore. as i was able to get the key during encryption / decription from the store itself.
but apparently according to 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42348944/calling-getencoded-on-secretkey-returns-null/42417197#42417197, i cannot encode a key in the keystore! seems need to find a new way

Comment: Sorry if miss something, but make sure about saving key,

Comment: Because you just prepare the generator, the generator instance will only generate the requested key based on your specs without saving it, and for mentioned question look at his question he did that, but you miss it. Hope you understand my point.